# Deserialize to type whose namespace has changed

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, binaryformatter, binary-serialization

Using .NET 4/C#...

I need to deserialize old config files that contain the serialized representation of a type named, say, ns1.X . The serialization has been done using `BinaryFormatter`.

The problem is, after a round of refactoring, the type X has been moved to a different namespace, say ns2.X .

I have tried creating a new empty ns1.X type that derives from ns2.X, and while this circumvents the '*Can't find type ns1.X*' error, the properties in the deserialized object are all `null`. Also, no ctors get called in the process.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if this can solve your problem since I never actually used it, but I remember reading up on TypeForwarding some time ago: you can find the info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404275.aspx

Comment: Interesting. I'll check it out.

Comment: A Google search found this which might help:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/DrawWithMouse.aspx#AdvancedBinarySerialization:DeserializinganObjectIntoaDifferentTypeThantheOneItwasSerializedInto9

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to use an [ISerializationSurregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188950.aspx) to make this happen. It's not too difficult and Jeff Richter explains it really well. I recommend his book CLR Via c# 3.